# wireless connection is not working ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: wireless, drivers

I installed ubuntu on my new computer dell inspiron 15 3000 series

before it was windows and wifi worked well on it .

but on ubuntu it just can't work

when I type `iwconfig` on terminal here's what i get :

```
eth0      no wireless extentions.

lo        no wireless extentions.
```

when i type `rfkill list all` i get :

```
 1: hci0 : Bluetooth 
           soft blocked : no 
           hard blocked : no
```

and when I type `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2`   i get :

```
06:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)

Subsystem: Dell Wireless 1704 802.11n + BT 4.0 [1028:0016]

Kernel driver in use: bcma-pci-bridge
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Comment: done editing @Pilot6 :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](http://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers)

Answer (score 0):

First go to System  Settings,  click on Software  & Updates.  Go to the Additional Drivers tab and see if the Broadcom card is listed.  If so click on the Broadcom option.

And reboot only  if the Broadcom source option appears.

IF there is no option for the Broadcom driver, in a terminal type  'sudo  apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras' then go back to System Settings/Software &  Updates.  Click on Additional  Drivers and choose Use Broadcom source option.

And again,  reboot.  I do the reboot because  I've occasionally had problems where I had to rechoose the option fot it to work,  but most of the time there were no problems.

Comment: i don't have a wireless connection driver that's the problem, how could i install that package without eth or wifi ?